# is there a quick way to delete a group and leave the objects?

Tags: groups

I added my objects into groups to append them easily and now I have got bunch of groups which I don't need anymore. how can I delete them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> opens the *remove from group* popup where you can remove all selected objects from all groups. When the last member of a group is removed the group itself will be dissolved.

[image]

Comment: Shift-Ctrl-Alt-G removes all selected objects from all groups. Ctrl-Alt-G just removes them from a group.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's clever to use the Outliner, choose `Groups` and then by Right clicking on it on the Group you want to delete, Unlink it:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I do think it's clever :)